# Why do links to twitter and direct links to tweets fail inside of Embedly?

Tags: embedly

We currently use Embedly for our mobile apps and have a feature to share links as news items. For most any normal link this works fine, pulls in the title, description and image. When attempting this for a tweet it fails? Is there a specific reason why Embedly may not allow links directly to a tweet? I'm getting the following error message when I try these types of links on the Embedly site:  Embedly is unable to generate an embed for this URL. Please check
that the URL is valid (has an http prefix: ex. http://embed.ly) and that
the content is publically accessable.